# WebView не видит localhost в смартфоне

Tags: android, kotlin

Версия моей windows 10 есть 1809

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Опция в настройках устарела

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключаю смартфон

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываю сайт в браузере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отображение сети моего смартфона

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Определяю IP адрес (ipconfig)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="ru.site.a1">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

 <application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/activity_main"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <WebView
  android:id="@+id/webView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***MainActivity.kt***

```
package ru.site.a1

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 private var url: String = ""

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

  url = "http://192.168.42.250:8000/"

  webView1.loadUrl(url)

 }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такая ошибка. Когда была версия windows10 1803 все было нормально. Подскажите, если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой. Спасибо.

Comment: В браузере на смартфоне попробуйте открыть. Если не откроется, то проблема чисто сетевая: порт закрыт, маршрута нет и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш сайт открывается по localhost - далеко не факт, что он открывается по 192.168.42.250 даже с самого компьютера. Проверьте брандмаузер, а еще некоторые антивирусы могут нее дать слушать порты. Если вы точно уверены, что страница доступна с других устройств, двигаемся дальше

Откройте в браузере телефона вашу страницу. Если откроется - будем дальше думать. Но я почти уверен, что не откроется. Телефон при создании интерфейса, чтобы "NATить" трафик компьютера, запросто может не создавать правил, разрешающих их прямое общение по этому интерфейсу. То есть проблема может пришла не с обновлением винды, а с обновлением телефона

Сделайте локальную сеть на роутере с вайфаем, это точно даст такую возможность. Если роутера нет - можно попробовать раздобыть вайфай-свисток для компьютера и раздать ему вайфай с телефона. Тоже не 100% вариант, но значительно более вероятный